# PHP: Base64 decode to convert string to other formats like decimal or binary

Tags: php, base64, converters

I'm trying to use a service which "base64 converts" their data which they then push to my server.  The data is divided into three data types: strings, integers and booleans.  Why they package it this way I don't understand, but it's up to me to decipher it.

I have a string `Qjo0MDk2` which should convert to `B:4096` and PHP's native `base64_decode` function works!

However, if I try to convert `AAATmg==` to a base-10 (decimal) integer value, I want to get `5018`, but `base64_decode` just gives me nothing.  (I assume because it's trying to convert to a string, rather than a base-10 integer.)

Likewise, `AA==` should convert to `0` in base-2 (binary) boolean values, while `AQ==` should convert to `1` in the same.

Is there a set of functions that does this already somewhere?  I can't imagine this is new.  Here is a website that does it today, but the code is not exposed: https://conv.darkbyte.ru/

Comment: `base64_decode` does give you something but it's binary, so if you dump it, it's just a character there is no actual character for (= the symbol with the question mark in it). There are functions to convert binary to decimal (and hex), tests show that I get `0` if I try `bindec`. It actually works if I go first to hexadecimal `hexdec(bin2hex(base64_decode(...)))`.

Comment: Just a heads up, the encoded value of `5018` appears to be `NTAxOA==` not `AAATmg==`.

Comment: @castis I'm not the one saying `AAATmg===` converts to `5018` -- that's what the third party is telling me and I'm trying to figure out how.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois That works for decimal/integer, thank you!  But then why doesn't this work for binary?  It always prints true when `AA==` should give `0` and `AQ==` should give `1`.  Code:  `if(base64_decode("AA==")) echo "true"; else echo "false";`

Comment: Here's why: https://3v4l.org/4C9l4 https://3v4l.org/sEXtd

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Thank you so much!  I'd been beating my head against this for several days!  If you submit as an answer I'll happily accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Binary data can't be simply printed, that's why you don't see something from `base64_decode`, but the data is there. If you want to actually see something, you need to convert the data to hexadecimal (technically into a hexadecimal representation). Since it looks like that the third party application is doing that (though in the other direction), you will have to do that for all data.

The data representation for `AA==` and `AQ==` is the same when you use them in an `if` statement, even though they are `00` and `01` hexadecimal-wise. They're `true`-ish to PHP, thus executing the `if` part. If you actually want to check their state, you will have to convert them to `int` (from the hexadecimal representation).

```
(int) bin2hex(base64_decode("AA==")) // int(0)
(int) bin2hex(base64_decode("AQ==")) // int(1)
```

Trying to convert from binary to `int` directly will result in `int(0)`. So you have to be cautious when you deal with data from the third party application.